# Button's event doesn't work after click on button's title or button's icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a dropdown button with  tag and a "down-caret" icon. when dropdown menu is open, "down-caret" icon should rotate up and this is working.

But if I click on button title or "down-caret" icon, this event not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown').click(function(e) {
    $($(e.target).find('.down-caret').toggleClass('open-caret'));
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(document).click(function() {
      $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('open');
      $('.down-caret').removeClass('open-caret');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown .drop {
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.down-caret {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6px;
  top: -3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
}

.open-caret {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="drop" href="#">
    <span>Dropdown</span>
    <i class="down-caret"></i>
  </a>
</li>
```

I need span & i tags to be exist in my code.

here is my complete code [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/ad4g12wj/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is, you are using currently clicked element `$(e.target)` to find an element inside with class `down-caret`.

And if you click on `icon` or the `text` there is no element inside with that specified class.

You just need to change `$(e.target)` to `$('.dropdown')` and you are done.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown').click(function(e){
    $('.dropdown').find('.down-caret').toggleClass('open-caret');
 
  });
  
 
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown .drop {
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.down-caret {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6px;
  top: -3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
}
.open-caret {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="dropdown">
   <a class="drop" href="#">
      <span>Dropdown</span>
      <i class="down-caret"></i>
   </a>
</li>
```

Here is the [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/ad4g12wj/35/)

Answer (score 6):

Just need to target the anchor element and change your JS slightly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a.drop').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.down-caret',this).toggleClass('open-caret');
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(document).click(function(){
      $('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('open');
      $('.down-caret').removeClass('open-caret');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown .drop {
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.down-caret {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-color: #ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6px;
  top: -3px;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
}
.open-caret {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown">
   <a class="drop" href="#">
      <span>Dropdown</span>
      <i class="down-caret"></i>
   </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is add this class in your CSS and the code will work as you want it to:

```
.drop{
  position:relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/thisisdg/ad4g12wj/54/) is the fiddle supporting it.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: thanks but i had been wanted that after click on white space, down-caret rotate down again. here problem was solved https://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/ad4g12wj/

Comment: okay, but I couldn't find any difference between this link and the one that I shared.

Comment: javascript - line 3 changed to : $($('.dropdown').find('.down-caret').toggleClass('open-caret'));

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using target to find the "down-caret" icon, why don't just take straight "down-icon"?

Change `$(e.target).find('.down-caret')` to `$('.down-caret')`

Answer (score 0):

I checked your fiddle code, and i just removed `<span>` and its working fine.
 I also updated your fiddle [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ad4g12wj/23/)

Comment: I noted that need <span> tag.