# Both span elements inside div not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have two span elements inside a div -

```
<div class="search-input">
  <div class="input-categories">
    <span class="comm-input-value">Any unit type </span>
    <span class="icon fa fa-angle-down"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

My jquery code is -

```
$('.input-categories').on('click',function(){
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass("open")){
             $(this).parent().removeClass("open");    

        }else {
            $('.input-categories').parent().removeClass('open');
            $(this).parent().addClass('open');

        }
});
```

Issue: Only the span with the icon is clickable. I want both the spans to be clickable and not just the icon span.
How can I achieve this? Please help

Comment: i cannot replicate the problem. See here http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/3946/ ( without refactoring your code which could be written better )

Comment: it works for me (span can be clicked)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button's event doesn't work after click on button's title or button's icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51278152/buttons-event-doesnt-work-after-click-on-buttons-title-or-buttons-icon)

Comment: Did you meant that cursor is not pointer.

Answer (score 4):

An elegant way to do it is by using toggleClass method of jquery.

```
<div class="search-input">
  <div class="input-categories">
    <span class="comm-input-value">Any unit type </span>
    <span class="icon fa fa-angle-down"></span>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
$('.input-categories span').on('click',function(){
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

put classes on your span elements (if those are the only spans which you want to get clicked) and bind click to those spans like this:

```
<div class="search-input">
  <div class="input-categories">

    <span class="comm-input-value input-span">Any unit type </span>
    <span class="icon fa fa-angle-down input-span"></span>

  </div>
</div>
```

and in Jquery no need to put the if else statement of removing open use toggle class

```
$('.input-span').on('click',function(){

             $(this).parent().toggleClass("open");    

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.input-categories').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
@import url("https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css");
@import url("https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css");
.input-categories {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="search-input">
  <div class="input-categories">
    <span class="comm-input-value">Any unit type </span>
    <span class="icon fa fa-angle-down"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are simple ways of writing the code. Why to write much when less can do?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well. Check it on this example:

```js
$('.input-categories').on('click',function(){
 alert("clicked");
});
```

```css
.icon{
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="search-input">
  <div class="input-categories">
    <span class="comm-input-value">Any unit type </span>
    <span class="icon fa fa-angle-down"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```